# tools to test Java soap based web services

Tags: java, web-services

Can any one tell me best web service test tools for SOAP based web services in JAVA.

It would be great if the tool is available as zip installation and open source.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOAPUI is the best [link](http://www.soapui.org/) , yes its opensource

Answer (score 2):

SOAP-UI is a great tool, and there is a free version: http://www.soapui.org/

You build test suites and test cases to run against your web services.  Results are saved in a JUnit-style report.

Test assertions can be done via XPath, or scripting.  The tool exposes an object model accessi ble via Groovy scripts.

Most Java developers feel comfortable with the tool.

Answer (score 1):

SOAP-UI is best tool for testing web services.
It offers

Functionality testing
Load testing
JMS or REST service testing
Mocking services where you can mock a static response or mock dynamic responses based on Xpath based query request.
It also offers options for Test Automation services.

Answer (score 1):

there is a good firefox plugin for accessing soap webservice, you can try that also. 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/soa-client/

Answer (score 0):

[REST-Client](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/) is another great framework , if you are testing REST based services